# KeychainItemWrapper class getting error in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychainitemwrapper

i want save password and id in my app. i downloaded

```
[KeychainItemWrapper][1]
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

and added KeychainItemWrapper.h/m in my project .when want to use class getting this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Better use other wrapper library than the one from Apple like [FXKeychain](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain) or [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) because the one from Apple does not support ARC, but if u want to use it then navigate to project's build phase -> Compile source -> Change that `KeychainItemWrapper.m` compiler flag to `-fno-objc-arc`

A newer keychain lib one is [Locksmith](https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith)

Comment: FXKeychain does not support ios 9. Data are not stored from some reason properly from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable ARC flag with fno-objc-arc compile flag in Project Settings -> Build Phases -> KeycchainItemWrapper.m